# Is it possible to detect that whether any modal dialog box is open over main window?

Tags: macos, qt, macos-carbon

Is it possible to detect that whether any modal dialog box is 
open over main window? If yes then how?

I am using Qt, Mac, Carbon.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetFrontWindowOfClass( kModalWindowClass, true ); should give you the answer you are looking for.

Unless something strange (i.e. buggy) is going on, a modal windows, by definition, will be higher then the main window.